# How do I make Susy 1 work?

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass

I'm totally confused by this whole susy/compass thing.  If I just try to include susy, then I get tons of errors about things like at-breakpoint not existing.  Googling says they're a susy 1 thing.  OK, so I try to use that, but now I get errors about susy/sass conflicts due to versions.  Some sites say use compass-susy-plugin, others say no, that's not version 1 then.

Does anyone have a decent install guide for getting susy/compass/grunt to all play nicely together?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use grunt, but I know that if you want to use Susy 1 you have to add:

```
@import "susyone";
```

to your scss file (_grids.sccs or style.scss). The instruction at-breakpoint has changed in the latest Susy 2 (specified as "susy" now).

Why not simply upgrade to Susy 2? You know it makes sense!!!

Comment: Because I was following a tutorial :)  I finally gave up, spent an hour, and got the packages I needed to make susy 2 work.